# Only Match Words That Are Outside of Certain Tags (Regex-JS)

Tags: javascript, php, regex, bbcode

I am working on writing my own BBCode parser. I am **VERY** new to writing Regexs.

I am trying to make it so that my regex would match all tags, except if they are inside of a `code` or `quote` tag. Here is what I mean:

```
[b] This text will be bolded [/b]

[code][b] This text will NOT be bolded [/b][/code]
[quote][b] This text will NOT be bolded [/b][/quote]
```

Problem is it is matching the text that SHOULD NOT be bolded...

Here is my regex:

```
/((?!\[code\]) \[b\](.*)\[\/b\] (?!=\/code\]))/gi
```

And you can find a working example here: https://regex101.com/r/oI3mN8/2

**So my question is, how can I make it grab the correct stuff?**

P.S. how can I make it grab each chunk? Right now it is grabbing the first and last. Example:

```
[b] This text should be bolded [/b]
This text should not be bolded, but it still is.
[b] This text should be bolded again [/b]
```

It for some reason is just grabbing the first and last tags, why?

Comment: "writing my own BBCode parser." for a start why ?

Comment: Well, I am coding my own forum website. Basically I wanna code everything on it. I felt it would (will) be fun to code my own BBCode Parser. I figured if I code it myself I will have complete control over it. Please do not suggest I use a BBCode library, that is something I MIGHT do in the long run. A bit opposite huh? xD

Comment: if i was to write my own forum, i would not  use BBCDOE - its dead. one of the WYSWYG editors such as: [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is a much nicer idea.

Comment: when did you last use a Builiten Board?

Comment: A while I guess, so you suggest a WYSWYG editor?

Comment: thats what i would do. but what do i know ;)

Comment: @Dagon, After much thinking, I will be going with BBCode. I have been reading up on WYSIWYG editors, and they seem a bit to hard to code for me at the moment. Now that I have decided that, any idea on how to fix my issue above? Thank You!

Comment: Actually they are  much easier than bbcode. anyway your call.

Comment: They don't seem it. They require an IFrame, and they seem very confuseing.

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation no iframe, replaces textarea 3 lines of code, no php or anything else once installed